# Finding the Pattern of a Gene Sequence Record Using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vim, pattern-matching, dna-sequence

What is the regular expression that I can use to remove the numbers and the white spaces in the following record?

```
    1 cctataactt ggaatgtggg tggaggggtt catagttctc cctgagtgag acttgcctgc
   61 ttctctggcc cctggtcctg tcctgttctc cagcatggtg tgtctgaagc tccctggagg
  121 ctcctgcatg acagcgctga cagtgacact gatggtgctg agctccccac tggctttgtc
  181 tggggacacc cgacgtaagt gcacattgcg ggtgctgagc tactatgggg tggggaaaat
 0921 ggcctgaagt cccagcattg atggcagcgc ctcatcttca acttttgtgc tcccctttgc
10981 ctaaaccgta tggcctcccg tgcatctgta ttcaccctgt atgacaaaca cattacatta
11041 ttaaatgttt ctcaaagatg gagttaaa
```

I used the following expression that match the pattern for all the lines except the last one:

```
(\s+\d+\s)\w+(\s)\w+(\s)\w+(\s)\w+(\s)\w+(\s)\w+(\s+)(\d+)
```

Comment: Maybe try `[^\d\s]+`

Comment: @l'L'l Your answer seems reasonable to me, but when I tired to run the expression in vim editor it does not work!  I am wondering why it is not working in vim?

Comment: I used `:%s/[^\d\s]+/g`

Comment: @MEhsan: FDinoff's pattern should work...

Comment: Vim is not Perl, you can't group `\d` and `\s` in `[\d\s]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
:%s/\d\+\|\s\+//g
```

to remove all numbers (`\d\+`) and whitespace (`\s\+`) from your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

in perl:

```
my $orig = q{
 1 cctataactt ggaatgtggg tggaggggtt catagttctc cctgagtgag acttgcctgc
61 ttctctggcc cctggtcctg tcctgttctc cagcatggtg tgtctgaagc tccctggagg
121 ctcctgcatg acagcgctga cagtgacact gatggtgctg agctccccac tggctttgtc
181 tggggacacc cgacgtaagt gcacattgcg ggtgctgagc tactatgggg tggggaaaat
0921 ggcctgaagt cccagcattg atggcagcgc ctcatcttca acttttgtgc tcccctttgc
10981 ctaaaccgta tggcctcccg tgcatctgta ttcaccctgt atgacaaaca cattacatta
11041 ttaaatgttt ctcaaagatg gagttaaa
};

## use this block if wish to extract each block
while ( $orig =~ /([atgc]{10})/simg )
{
  print "$1\n";
}

## or this block to get single string without numbers,spaces or newlines
$orig =~ s/[\d|\W]+//smg;
## or to retain newlines

print $orig;
```

Comment: I presume you mean `[\d\W]` instead of `[\d|\W]`.  This is better written as `perl -lpe 's/[\d\s]//g' file` anyway.